# With PHP execute .exe file on different server

Tags: php, exec, exe

I have an `php` application hosted on lampp over ubuntu server.

I  want to call an `.exe` file hosted on a **different** server.

This file does some functionality and returns a result. It takes a filename as a parameter and returns a string.

How through `php` can I execute this `.exe` file (on another server) and pass paramters to it.

Comment: We need more details about the **other** server. What type of server is it and how does it expose the file?

Answer (score 0):

exe file will execute on windows server.You will need to create service on windows server which will execute exe file.Then your php application hosted on lampp can call that service.

Comment: I see ... how can i call this service throw my app and pass a parameter to

Comment: You can access this service by calling URL and can pass parameters by using GET method..